# JAVA: Activating a jFrameButton on "enter" key press when a jTextField is selected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have a program with a `JFrame` GUI and I want a button to be clicked when the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from within a `JTextField`. Yes I have tried

```
rootPane.setDefaultButton(jButton5);
```

but it only works when the text field isn't selected. How could I have it click the button when the text field is selected?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: You could add an `ActionListener` to the field and call `doClick` on the button

Comment: Just add the same ActionListener to the JTextField that you add to the JButton.

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    jButton5.doClick();

            }});
```

JTextField is you text field component. Then when you click the enter key, doClick method of JButton is invoked which Programmatically perform a "click". This does the same thing as if the user had pressed and released the button.

Comment: -1, This was already suggested 40 minutes earlier and variable names should not start with an upper case character.

Comment: @camickr, I know variable names should not start with an upper case character, the author should replace the name with his var name. Maybe the answer is more detailed than that of 40 min ago.

Comment: So why does the button have a proper name? Be consistent, don't promote bad habbits. Suggest a proper name to be used. Also, there is no need for detail since the OP already knows how to write an ActionListener, since they added one to the button, which is why they want to do the click on the button.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to add `actionListener` to `textField` and override method `actionPerformed()`

```
text.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Text=" + text.getText());
        //Your logic
      }
});
```

Comment: -1, it has already been suggested to add an ActionListener. You have not added anything new to the topic. Also the fact that you are creating a new ActionListener is a bad idea. It has already been suggested that you either share the ActionListener of the button or invoke doClick() on the button.

Comment: this achieves OP's basic requirement.

Comment: No, you should not write a separate ActionListener. The same ActionListener that is used for the button should be used for the text field.